# What's the easiest way to get an iPhone 3GS movie into iMovie?

Tags: iphone, iphoto, imovie

It seems like the steps right now are:

1. Shoot movie
2. sync iPhone with Mac via iTunes
3. Open iPhoto
4. Import photos from iPhone into iPhoto
5. Open iMovie (or retart if it was already running)
6. On startup, iMovie detects videos in iPhoto and imports them.

Yikes. Is there an easier way? It's a bit odd that the videos are handled as photos, in the first place.

And no, I'm not jailbreaking my iPhone simply to save me a few of these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're finding the iPhoto portion a bit tedious you can try a program such as [Clipstart](http://www.riverfold.com/software/clipstart/) which focuses completely on movies but you'll still have to import it into iMovie.

Unfortunately at present there is no seamless way to get the videos from the iPhone direct to iMovie without first stopping off in iPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

(OK so I just checked this at home)

1. Connect iPhone 3GS using iPod cable.
2. Launch Image Capture app.
3. Select movies/images to import.
4. Launch iMovie and use File > Import > Movies... and browse to folder where you saved the movies.

Okay so I admit this is just substituting iPhoto with Image Capture, but the latter app is much more lightweight I guess... but then again if you use iPhoto then all your imported iPhone movies become available in the 'media browser' for other apps in iLife/iWork.

--
dp